# Django aggregate Count only True values

Tags: python, django, aggregate

I'm using aggregate to get the count of a column of booleans. I want the number of True values.

DJANGO CODE:

```python
count = Model.objects.filter(id=pk).aggregate(bool_col=Count('my_bool_col')
```

This returns the count of all rows.

SQL QUERY SHOULD BE:

```sql
SELECT count(CASE WHEN my_bool_col THEN 1 ELSE null END) FROM <table_name>
```

Here is my actual code:

```python
stats = Team.objects.filter(id=team.id).aggregate(
    goals=Sum('statistics__goals'),
    assists=Sum('statistics__assists'),
    min_penalty=Sum('statistics__minutes_of_penalty'),
    balance=Sum('statistics__balance'),
    gwg=Count('statistics__gwg'),
    gk_goals_avg=Sum('statistics__gk_goals_avg'),
    gk_shutout=Count('statistics__gk_shutout'),
    points=Sum('statistics__points'),
)
```

Thanks to **Peter DeGlopper** suggestion to use [django-aggregate-if](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-aggregate-if/)

Here is the solution:

```python
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models import Q
from aggregate_if import Count

stats = Team.objects.filter(id=team.id).aggregate(
    goals=Sum('statistics__goals'),
    assists=Sum('statistics__assists'),
    balance=Sum('statistics__balance'),
    min_penalty=Sum('statistics__minutes_of_penalty'),
    gwg=Count('statistics__gwg', only=Q(statistics__gwg=True)),
    gk_goals_avg=Sum('statistics__gk_goals_avg'),
    gk_shutout=Count('statistics__gk_shutout', only=Q(statistics__gk_shutout=True)),
    points=Sum('statistics__points'),
)
```

Comment: Why is this not just `SELECT count(*) FROM <table name> WHERE my_bool_col = 1`? There's a simple expression for that query in Django, but either I don't understand what you're trying to do or you're doing this an unnecessarily hard way in SQL.

Comment: I added another example with my actual code to better explain

Comment: I am not sure that this will work, but have you tried whether the API allows you to call `Sum` on a `BooleanField`? It's kind of a hack, but since the DB representation is either 1 or 0 the math works out right. Failing that, this third-party library looks relevant: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-aggregate-if/

Comment: Sum doesn't work. I'll give it a try, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update:

Since Django 1.10 you can:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When
query_set.aggregate(
    bool_col=Count(
        Case(When(my_bool_col=True, then=Value(1)))
    )
)
```

Read about the [Conditional Expression classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#the-conditional-expression-classes)

### Old answer.

It seems what you want to do is some kind of **"Conditional aggregation"**. Right now `Aggregation` functions do not support lookups like `filter` or `exclude`: fieldname__lt, fieldname__gt, ...

So you can try this:

[django-aggregate-if](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-aggregate-if)

Description taken from the official page.

> Conditional aggregates for Django queries, just like the famous SumIf and CountIf in Excel.

You can also first [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the desired value for each team, I mean count for each team the ammount of `True` in the field you are interested. And then do all the [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) you want to do.

Comment: While appropriate for the time of the query, instead look at the built-in conditional aggregation functionality of Django.  Django-aggregate-if hasn't been updated, presumably due to the functionality being rolled into Django.

(Presumably since there is no indication of why it hasn't been updated.)

Comment: @BenjaminSchollnick, That's true, Answer updated. Thanks.

Comment: `Count()` seems to count non-`null` values so that `Value(0)` counts as well as `Value(1)` or `Value(42)`... Use `default=Value(None)` instead to properly count using `Count()`. Or simple remove the `default=` as it seems to default to `None` (=`null`)

Answer (score 32):

Updated for Django 1.10. You can perform conditional aggregation now:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When
query_set.aggregate(bool_col=Count(Case(When(my_bool_col=True, then=1))))
```

More information at:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case

Comment: This answer is more up to date and a better option over the 3rd party django-aggregate-if module

Comment: Extremely helpful, and significantly better than a 3rd party plugin/library that hasn't been updated to work past django 1.08.

Comment: @Purrell Thanks for pointing out my answer was deprecated, I've updated the answer so is still being the answer for those still working with old Django versions and those working with modern Django versions. Thanks.

Comment: `then=1` without a default is correct here.  I ran into issues with `then=Value(1)` and `default = Value(0)` where the `Count()` call counted all values, so I'd get a `Count()` of 87 when I really only had 76 Trues.

Answer (score 6):

Another Solution for count Bool is:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

Model.objects.filter(id=pk).annotate(bool_col=Sum(Cast('my_bool_col', IntegerField())))
```

Just convert `False` to 0 and `True` to 1, and then just `Sum`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Sum, Count, Q 

aggregated_values = queryset.aggregate(
        avg_length=Avg('field_name'),
        total_reserved=Count('field_name', filter=Q(field_name=True)),
        total_not_reserved=Count('field_name', filter=Q(field_name=False))
    )
```