# How to count more than one fields and grouping them using django orm

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I am a newbie to Django and its ORM.

Table `User` is having many users. I need to group active users and total 
users from the table and also I need to order them based on the year they have joined using Django ORM
in sql, This could be like,

```
select count('users'), 
count('users' where is_active is True as 'active_users') form user 
order by 'created_at'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get all users include active users
users = User.objects.all().order_by('created_at')
users_count = users.count() 
# Get only active users
active_users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('created_at')
active_users_count = active_users.count()
```

> group active users and total users from the table

as for aggregation, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250490/django-aggregate-count-only-true-values)